# JQuery UI Modal box

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

When I create a modal box everything works perfectly. However when I want to open another modal box by clicking the OK button from the first modal box this will open up the next modal box but the CSS for applying the image background with recude opactiy does not seem to be used once this happens.

Has anyone ever tried this and if so is there some way I can make this style still apply when the second modal box opens and the first one closes.

Thanks
Rory

```
$('#dialog1').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

$('#dialog2').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                                $('#dialog2').dialog('open');
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by simply adding the overlay to the `<body>` via JQuery